# How to send `eof` signal, over a socket, to a command running in remote shell?

Tags: linux, sockets, python-3.x, signals

> How to send `eof` signal, over a socket, to a command running in remote shell?

I've programmed in Python, using sockets, a remote shell application, where I send commands to be executed on another PC.

Everything works fine (for most commands), except a command like `cat > file` is causing me problems.

Normally, I would terminate the command above with `CTRL + D` (`eof` signal), but pressing `CTRL + D` in my client, doesn't send the signal to the remote shell. Therefore I have no means of terminating the command and I'm stuck.

Anyone have suggestions ?

Answer (score 7):

eof is not a signal but is implemented by the tty driver as a read of length 0 when you type <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd>.

If your remote is not running in a tty then you cannot generate an eof as you cannot send a packet that reads as of length 0. However if you run a program like `script /dev/null` as the first command in your remote shell, then this will envelop your shell inside a pseudo-tty, and you will be able to send a real <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> character (hex 0x04) and the pty will convert this to eof and end a cat, for example. Send a `stty -a` to the remote to check that eol is enabled in your pty.

---

`stty -a` on my terminal says `lnext = ^V` (literal-next char) so I can type <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> to input a real hex 0x04 char.

I chose `script` as I know it effectively interposes a pseudo-tty in the communication, and does nothing to the data stream. This is not its original purpose (see its man page), but that doesn't matter.

Comment: How do I send such hex value from my terminal ? Why do script /dev/null create a terminal ? I use this file for garbage normally.

Comment: I added my reply to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is very technical for a newbie like me; but I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use 'here' syntax instead to mark the EOF:

```
cat > file <<-EOF
...
...
EOF
```

or just `cat > file <<<"whatever you like to type in"` No delimeter is needed here.

The above is documented very nicely in Bash manual. Don't know if other shells support this, though.